# Splitting or Chunking NSData on specific value(s) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I'm trying to figure out how to "chunk" a `NSData` on a specific value.

#### Input Data

`7E 55 33 22 7E 7E 22 AE BC 7E 7E AA AA 00 20 00 22 53 25 A3 4E 7E`

#### Output Data

Returns an array of 3 elements of type `[NSData]` where the elements are:

- `55 33 22`
- `22 AE BC`
- `AA AA 00 20 00 22 53 25 A3 4E`

#### Where I'm at

I know I can do something like:

```
var ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)
var bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: ptr, count: data.length)
```

And I guess iterate through doing a comparison similar to:

```
bytes[1] == UInt8(0x7E)
```

And I guess build up "ranges" but I was wondering if there is a better way to go about this?

#### Code Stub

```
private fund chunkMessage(data: NSData) -> [NSData] {
  var ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)
  var bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: ptr, count: data.length)
  var ret = []

 // DO SOME STUFF

  return ret as! [NSData];

}
```

Comment: Maybe with some method of `NSData` (`subdataWithRange:`) or `rangeOfData:option:range:` (with a for loop since it returns only the first occurence)

Comment: I'm coming at this from the Objective-C side. It looks like your approach is pretty reasonable. (Although I would think you'd want to create Swift arrays of UInt8's instead of NSArrays out of your components.) I'm still learning about how Swift deals with things like byte pointers. Can you tell me where to read about things like UnsafeBufferPointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably many possible solutions. A straight-forward way, using
`NSData` methods, would be

```
func chunkMessage(data: NSData, var separator : UInt8) -> [NSData] {
    let sepdata = NSData(bytes: &separator, length: 1)
    var chunks : [NSData] = []

    // Find first occurrence of separator:
    var searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, data.length)
    var foundRange = data.rangeOfData(sepdata, options: nil, range: searchRange)
    while foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
        // Append chunk (if not empty):
        if foundRange.location > searchRange.location {
            chunks.append(data.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(searchRange.location, foundRange.location - searchRange.location)))
        }
        // Search next occurrence of separator:
        searchRange.location = foundRange.location + foundRange.length
        searchRange.length = data.length - searchRange.location
        foundRange = data.rangeOfData(sepdata, options: nil, range: searchRange)
    }
    // Check for final chunk:
    if searchRange.length > 0 {
         chunks.append(data.subdataWithRange(searchRange))
    }
    return chunks
}
```

As already suggested in the comments, you could work with Swift arrays
instead. Here is a possible implementation:

```
func chunkMessage(data: NSData, separator : UInt8) -> [[UInt8]] {

    let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(data.bytes), count: data.length)

    // Positions of separator bytes:
    let positions = filter(enumerate(bytes), { $1 == separator } ).map( { $0.0 } )

    // Non-empty ranges between the separator bytes:
    let ranges = map(Zip2([-1] + positions, positions + [bytes.count])) {
        (from : Int, to : Int) -> (Int, Int) in
        (from + 1, to - from - 1)
        }.filter( { $1 > 0 } )

    // Byte chunks between the separator bytes:
    let chunks = map(ranges) {
        (start: Int, count : Int) -> [UInt8] in
        Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bytes.baseAddress + start, count: count))
    }

    return chunks
}
```

I leave it to you to test which one performs better :)

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar situation but I just wanted to chunk my data by specific sizes, here's how I got it to work in swift 2.0. This assumes that "data" is of type NSData and is already filled with the info you want to split:

```
    let length = data.length
    let chunkSize = 1048576      // 1mb chunk sizes
    var offset = 0

    repeat {
        // get the length of the chunk
        let thisChunkSize = ((length - offset) > chunkSize) ? chunkSize : (length - offset);

        // get the chunk
        let chunk = data.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(offset, thisChunkSize))

        // -----------------------------------------------
        // do something with that chunk of data...
        // -----------------------------------------------

        // update the offset
        offset += thisChunkSize;

    } while (offset < length);
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: @adan1985.. will this apply to video or audio files as well? my use case is I want to divide the mp4 files into chunks and later I can accumulate them to make a complete file again?

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3 solution u used based on adan1985

```
  let length = data.count
  let chunkSize = 500
  var offset = 0

  repeat {
    // get the length of the chunk
    let thisChunkSize = ((length - offset) > chunkSize) ? chunkSize : (length - offset);

    // get the chunk
    let chunk = data.subdata(in: offset..<offset + thisChunkSize )

    // -----------------------------------------------
    // do something with that chunk of data...
    // -----------------------------------------------

    // update the offset
    offset += thisChunkSize;

  } while (offset < length);
```

Comment: nice ; swift3 solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 this would work, with an extension to `Data`

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa
import Foundation

var str = "Hello, playground"

let d : Data = Data(bytes: [0x7E, 0x55, 0x33, 0x22, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0x22, 0xAE, 0xBC, 0x7E, 0x7E, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x22, 0x53, 0x25, 0xA3, 0x4E, 0x7E])

let f = d.separateData(bySeparator: 0x7E)
print(f) // [[0x55, 0x33, 0x22],[0x22, 0xAE, 0xBC],[0xAA, 0xAA, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x22, 0x53, 0x25, 0xA3, 0x4E]
//
//  Data+Separate.swift
//  Created by Julian Bleecker on 6/7/17.
//


public extension Data {

    /// Separate data into an array of an array of Int8
    func separateData(bySeparator : UInt8) -> [[UInt8]] {
        let bytes = [UInt8](self)

        let split = bytes.split(separator: bySeparator)

        let bunks = split.enumerated().map( { $0.1 } )

        let chunks = bunks.enumerated().map( {
            Data.init($0.element).toArray(type: UInt8.self)
        })

        return chunks
    }
    /// Bonus. Convert to an array of Strings which would be separated by nulls
    func separateDataToStrings(encoding: String.Encoding)  -> [String] {
        let strunks: [String] = self.separateData(bySeparator: 0x00).enumerated().map( {
            let d: Data = Data.init(bytes: $0.element)
            return String(data: d, encoding: .utf8)!
        })
        return strunks
    }

    func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return self.withUnsafeBytes {
            [T](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: self.count/MemoryLayout<T>.stride))
        }
    }
}
```